# Accessing key using kv filter in logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

Can ruby be used inside kv in logstash. Is there any way to access the key? Will this work? Please help.

```
 filter {

    kv {
            source => "[url][queryString]"
            field_split => "&"
            target => "kv"
            ruby {
    key, value = kv.split ': ', 2      

            if (key =~ /^.{50,}$/) {
                 mutate {
              remove_field => [ "[url][queryString]" ]
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have my url querystring of the format key1=val1&key2=val2...(variable length)   I need to extract the key and check on it's length. Can anyone possibly give a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kv{} and ruby{} are both filters, so they're peers to each other and must appear at the same level.

If you posted the problem you were trying to solve, perhaps someone could help you.

Comment: Thanks. I will try and use only ruby to extract the key.